# Does Bluemix Data Cache Service work cross instance

Tags: caching, service, ibm-cloud

I assume that if I would use the datacache service for an application in Bluemix with several instances, the service would be using the same cache for all instances. But as I can't find anything in the documentation stating this I ask the question here to be sure I haven't got it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah the Data Cache service works across instances.  Think of it like a shared database.  The information in it will be available to all of your instances of your app.

Comment: Thnx this was the answer I hoped for.